Landscape Server clients Duplicates
I have few servers registered with the landscape server, some of the servers are registered multiple times , eg one server having 450 entries , some more serves having 2 or more entries as duplicates , how to identify the duplicate servers are remove for the landscape server , how to identify which entry is communicating to the  landscape server .
